# prepareForSegue with customCell in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have a controller with a listview that contain a custom cell.

I have created a modal segue from the cell to the next controller and I gave a name to this segue but when I click on the cell, `prepareForSegue` isn't called.

I could use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `performSegueWithIdentifier` but I have to send data to the next controller from the cell I've clicked on.

Any idea why the `prepareForSegue` isn't called? Or how to send data to the controller with another method?

Comment: Why would `prepareForSegue` be called? Did you wire it to your custom cell?

Comment: What you describe should work, and any data you need to pass should be done in prepareForSegue. Check to make sure you connected the segue from the cell, and that the cell is actually responding to touches (implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and just put a log inside to to see if it's called).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell data in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` by getting the cell from the index of customCell that you clicked, and after you can `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

So let's make this easier:

Under your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, add this line to get the properties of your customCell

```
YourCustomCell *customCell = (YourCustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

So now if you have something stored under your customCell you can access it from `customCell` instance.
After you managed to store or manipulate your data from customCell you do the `performSegueWithIndenfier`:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:self];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

When you connect a segue from a cell to another view controller, unless it's a static table view, you'll have to trigger `performSegueWithIdentifier` from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

After you execute `performSegueWithIdentifier`, `prepareForSegue` would be called.

In `prepareForSegue`, you can set up your destination view controller, which you can access via `segue.destinationViewController`

Like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:sender sender:sender];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"]) {
      UIViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

Or if you need to set things up in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , you could do (iOS7+ only)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE" sender:self];
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = [self.transitionCoordinator viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
}
```

**Update:**

Turns out @rdelmar is correct, it does work with dynamic cells.

All you have to do then is

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:sender sender:sender];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"]) {
       NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    }
}
```

And you have the index path of the cell that was tapped. Then you can use that to query your datasource and find the object that was used to populate that cell.

Comment: This is wrong. If you connect the segue from the cell itself, there's no need to use performSegueWithIdentifier.